# Are cosets groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I ran into this question when reading Artin's Algebra book and tried to google the answer but seems it's too easy that I didn't get any.

My answer is: Not necessarily.

Proof:

From the definition of a left coset: $aH=\{ah\ |\ h\in H\}$, where $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, and $a\in G$.

If we want $aH$ to be a group, it has to be a closure: $ah_{1}ah_{2}\in aH$, thus $h_{1}ah_{2}\in H$. And since $a\in G$ according to the assumption, $h_{1}ah_{2}\notin H$. So cosets are not necessarily groups.

Am I correct? Thanks.

Comment: A subgroup has to contain the identity!

Comment: @Pedrom I don't understand your comment --- certainly $3{\bf Z}$ is closed under addition. $3+{\bf Z}$ isn't....

Comment: @GerryMyerson $3+\Bbb Z$ is closed under addition!

Comment: Aargh.... Maybe I was thinking of $3+2{\bf Z}$, or something like that.

Comment: You are being a little sloppy with your terminology. A group for which law? For the law induced by that of $G$ it is clear that a coset of $H \le G$ in $G$ is not in general a group, because it may lack an identity.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Hah, seems a proof through identity is simpler... Thank you! And can you explain the difference between $3Z$ and $3+Z$? I don't quite get a catch...

Comment: $3{\bf Z}$ is the set of all multiples of 3. $3+{\bf Z}$ is what you get when you add 3 to every integer, which just gives you $\bf Z$.

Comment: By the way, you can write up and post an answer using the identity, and then you can accept it, and help clear the unanswered questions list. The software may make you wait a while to do this.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Oh I'm completely confused with Artin's terminology... He uses $3Z$ for $3+Z$....

Comment: @GerryMyerson Now there are two answers:)

Comment: I wish people would be a little more patient and let authors solve their own questions.

Comment: @fkraiem Since I'm kind of losing in the book so I began to talk about additive groups without any clarification... Thanks:)

Comment: @GerryMyerson Is my proof through the closure property correct?

Comment: You haven't supported the assertion that since $a$ is in $G$, $h_1ah_2$ is not in $H$. And indeed that assertion is false if $a$ is in $H$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Eh, can I say "Because $a$ is not necessarily in $G$, so $h_{1}ah_{2}$ is not necessarily in $H$"?

Comment: But $a$ *is* in $G$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry for the typo... I mean $a$ is not necessarily in $H$.

Comment: That's good, but a few words as to why "$a$ not in $H$" implies "$h_1ah_2$ not in $H$" would be a good idea.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A coset is a set while a group is a set together with a binary operation that satisfies some axioms. So, a coset is not a group since the binary operation is missing. Any question asking whether a given set is a group is a wrong question. If you meant to ask if a coset is a subgroup (of the obvious ambient group), then that can be answered negatively by noticing that the identity element, which must be an element of any subgroup, is not necessarily an element in a coset.

Comment: You couldn't wait for OP to do this?

Comment: Yeah I considered for a while about this but finally decided to ask about "groups" for being a subgroup needs even more conditions. So seems I asked a question not rigorous enough. Thanks:)

Answer (score 3):

A coset $aH$ is a *subgroup* of $G$ iff $aH=H$ because a subgroup must contain the identity of $G$.

A coset $aH$ is always a *group* under the law $ah\cdot ah’ = a hh’$. In this case, $a$ acts as the identity and the inverse of $ah$ is $ah^{-1}$.

In linear algebra, cosets appear as affine subspaces: they look just like subspaces but they’re not, unless they go through the origin. Affine subspaces are just translations of subspaces. You can make an affine subspace into a vector space by choosing an origin in them. It’s just not the same origin as that of the whole space.

Comment: Your second line is actually defining multiple different group laws, one for every choice of coset representative.

Comment: This if of great help. Thank you. I just wanted to ask how to prove "other cosets do not contain the identity" but seems it's easy. Because if we want $ah=1$, then we need to find a $h=a^{-1}$, which is not possible since $a\in G$ and if we have $a^{-1}$ then $a$ is also defined.